# how to use vertical menu using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, menu, master-pages

In my master page (his name is menu.master) , i want to create 3 menu , the first (title) , the second (example2) and the footer (copyright ) 
my question is : how to make (

here is my code in masterpage

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="title" style="background-color:red";>
    <a href="test1.aspx" runat="server">Home</a>
    <asp:label id="Label2" Text="Bienvenue" runat="server"></asp:label>
    <asp:label id="Label3" Text="Exit" runat="server"></asp:label>
    </div>         
      <div class="example2" style="background-color:green;position:fixed;">      
        <a href="contact.aspx"  runat="server">Contacter </a><br /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="test" Text="Test" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="barreMenu" runat="server">     
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <div class="footer" style="position:fixed;background-color:yellow;width:100%;bottom:0;">
    <h3>...........</h3>
    </div>
    </form>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Copy And Paste and name it as Menu.css**

```css
#cssmenu {
  position: relative; 
  background:#DCDCDC;
  width:100%;
  
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background:Skyblue;
  width: 100%;
  
  
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
  
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
  
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
}
#cssmenu > ul > #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-family:Times New Roman;
  text-decoration: none;
 
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  color: Black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 32px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu li.has-sub::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub::after {
  right: 10px;
  top: 20px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #7a8189;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover::after {
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
}
#indicatorContainer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}
#pIndicator {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #2b2f3a;
  z-index: -2;
  -webkit-transition: left .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: left .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: left .25s ease;
  -o-transition: left .25s ease;
  transition: left .25s ease;
}
#cIndicator {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #2b2f3a;
  top: -12px;
  right: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: 70px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  top: 37px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  top: 44px;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 170px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 170px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  width: 130px;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid #eeeeee;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: Black;
  background:#DCDCDC;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .35s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .35s ease;
  -o-transition: all .35s ease;
  transition: all .35s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li a {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: #8c9195;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul::after {
  content: '';
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  left: 30px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > ul::after {
  left: auto;
  right: 30px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub::after {
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #9ea2a5;
  right: 10px;
  top: 12px;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease, right 0.2s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub::after {
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: #9ea2a5;
  right: auto;
  left: 10px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover::after {
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
  right: -5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub:hover::after {
  border-right-color: #ffffff;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  left: -5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu {
    width: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul {
    width: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenuArrow,
  #cssmenu #indicatorContainer {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul {
    height: auto;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu li,
  #cssmenu > ul > li {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul > li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul > li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul > li:hover > ul {
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    right: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu ul .has-sub::after {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a {
    padding: 12px 20px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    width: auto;
    padding: 8px 35px;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul li a {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
    background: none;
    color: #8c9195;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 50px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 65px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 80px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 95px;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > #menu-button {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button > a {
    padding: 12px 20px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul.open li,
  #cssmenu > ul.open > li {
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul.open > li#menu-button > a {
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.1);
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul::after {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 0px solid #7a8189;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #7a8189;
    right: 20px;
    top: 15px;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 0px solid #7a8189;
    right: 20px;
    top: 25px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul.open #menu-button::after,
  #cssmenu ul.open #menu-button::before {
    border-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

**In form**

```
<table width="100%">
        <td style="width: 200px" valign="top">
            <div id="cssmenu">
                <ul id="">
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Admin</span></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Test1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Master</span></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">test2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"><span>test</span></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Test2</a>
                            <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Test2-test</a>
                            </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use For Has Sub else Avoid**

```
    <script>
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#cssmenu').prepend('<div id="indicatorContainer"><div id="pIndicator"><div id="cIndicator"></div></div></div>');
            var activeElement = $('#cssmenu>ul>li:first');

            $('#cssmenu>ul>li').each(function() {
                if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                    activeElement = $(this);
                }
            });


            var posLeft = activeElement.position().left;
            var elementWidth = activeElement.width();
            posLeft = posLeft + elementWidth / 2 - 6;
            if (activeElement.hasClass('has-sub')) {
                posLeft -= 6;
            }

            $('#cssmenu #pIndicator').css('left', posLeft);
            var element, leftPos, indicator = $('#cssmenu pIndicator');

            $("#cssmenu>ul>li").hover(function() {
                element = $(this);
                var w = element.width();
                if ($(this).hasClass('has-sub')) {
                    leftPos = element.position().left + w / 2 - 12;
                }
                else {
                    leftPos = element.position().left + w / 2 - 6;
                }

                $('#cssmenu #pIndicator').css('left', leftPos);
            }
, function() {
    $('#cssmenu #pIndicator').css('left', posLeft);
});

            $('#cssmenu>ul').prepend('<li id="menu-button"><a>Menu</a></li>');
            $("#menu-button").click(function() {
                if ($(this).parent().hasClass('open')) {
                    $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
                }
                else {
                    $(this).parent().addClass('open');
                }
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);

</script>
```

**Use Your Own Footer...**